# Statistics about Significant security breaches in 2013

Tags: intrusion

I am curious in general if there are any reporting that collects statistics about the security breaches? like per country per industry and revenue losses?

I am not interested in anonymized breaches like the ones of Verizon et al. I am interested in breaches admitted by their own companies, like (for example the [LinkedIn breach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_LinkedIn_hack). If there are none, I would appreciate community's help in collecting those for 2013.

Comment: Can i ask what you are interested in using this for?

Comment: Check [VERIS](http://www.veriscommunity.net/doku.php). although "most important" is an opinion term and inappropriate for SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, although it focuses on dataloss as opposed to specifically security breaches, would be [the data loss db](http://datalossdb.org/).

In terms of the most important breach of 2013 as mentioned in comments already that's subjective, but arguably one could suggest that the NSAs data loss was the most significant of last year

Answer (score 1):

I generally read technology news to keep me update about security breaches. Few are the sources I generally used and you can read archive for 2013 references.

http://www.bbc.com/news/technology/

http://edition.cnn.com/TECH/

I further recommend reading  [2013 Cost of Cyber Crime Study](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://media.scmagazine.com/documents/54/2013_us_ccc_report_final_6-1_13455.pdf&ei=q7P7UqGPK9GAhQeS04DQBg&usg=AFQjCNFCeLscVIrhvfBbHjzjrUAF51yUZw&sig2=GdFy6QjrGF3ElkFs9Ixr_g&bvm=bv.61190604,d.ZG4) report